# Ember Route with renderTemplate and two render calls overrides original model

Tags: ember.js

I have an outlet in `application.hbs` called 'sidebar'. This outlet is used in some routes to render additional info using a component called 'sidebar-info'. In those routes I use `renderTemplate` to render stuff in the appropriate outlets. For example:

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('components/sidebar-info', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'sidebar',
        model: Ember.Object.create({
            title: this.get('i18n').t('signup'),
            detailsComponent: 'signup-help'
        })
    });
    this.render('sign-up');
},
```

This is `components/sidebar-info` template:

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>{{model.title}}</h1>
</div>
{{#if model.detailsComponent}}
<div class="details">
    {{component model.detailsComponent}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

When the route template (not the component one) is being rendered, the model defined by the route is overwritten by the model sent to the component. If the original model was something like this:

```
original_model = {
   field_1: 1,
   field_2: 2
}
```

Then using `model.field_1` becomes undefined in the context of the template while `model.title` is available.

Why is the model being overwritten?

---

I am using Ember 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is the correct behaviour. According to the [Route API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate), this is the explanation of the controller and model options sent to the render method:

> **controller** [String|Object]
>
> the controller to use for this template, referenced by name or as a
>   controller instance. Defaults to the Route's paired controller
>
> **model** [Object]
>
> the model object to set on `options.controller`. Defaults to the
>   return value of the Route's model hook

This means that setting **only** the model option will set the model on the Route's paired controller because **that is the default** `option.controller`. This means we need either to create a dummy controller that only works to receive the model.

I have tested this and it works as expected.